# Keeping data from detached Checkbox

Tags: javascript, html

I have an app I am creating, I've been able to get through it so far relatively hassle free. Until now. At the moment I need to find a way to keep the information produced by if statements for a check box. I have been able to get this working for a radio button by just storing the data in a global variable but I am not sure how to with a check box.

Code:

```
if ($('#Chk_0').is(':checked')) {
    check = "Check1" + ", ";
    countCheck++;
}

if ($('#Chk_1').is(':checked')) {
    check = "Check2" + ", ";
    countCheck++;
}

if (countCheck == 0) {
    Check = "Nothing is checked";
}
```

Checkbox:

```
<div data-role="collapsible" id="cCheck" class="hCheck">
  <h3>CheckBox</h3>
  <div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
      <legend>Option</legend>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Check" id="Check_0" class="custom" value="" />
      <label for="Check_0">Check1</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Check" id="Check_1" class="custom" value="" />
      <label for="Check_1">Check2</label>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can u put it in a jsfiddle?

Comment: Doesn't that just test code? I am after keeping the value of the check boxes after I detach it. At the moment I have kind of solved it with saving each individual check in a separate variable but that really isn't an effective solution.

Comment: not clear what exactly you are looking for ..can you please post your working code for radio button

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array and a string.

```
var checkedOptions=[]
var checkedGroup="";

if ($('#Check_0').is(':checked')) {
    if(checkGroup=="Check"){
    checkedGroup.push("Check_0");
    }
    else
    {
    checkGroup="Check"
    checkedGroup=["Check0"];
    }
    countCheck++;
}
```

BTW: You have an error in your code. The IDs of the input tags and the jQuery are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand your question ,you need to know is any check box is checked and if any checked you need the ids so this may be help

```
var ids = '';
$(':checked').each(function (i, element) {
    ids += $(element).prop('id')+",";
})
```

then you can chekc if ids has length

```
if (ids.length>0) {
    //use ids variable here
}
```